# updating variable after ajax call made in angularjs

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I use factory to make database calls in angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.factory("Service", function ($http) {
  var obj = {};
  $http.get('test.txt').then(function (data) {
    obj.getApiKey = {'Authorization' : data.data};
  });
  return obj;
});
app.factory("Orders", function ($http, Service) {
  var obj = {};
  var api_key = Service.getApiKey;
  console.log(api_key);
  return obj;
});
```

In the above program, when i call property of Service factory and log the value of **api_key = Service.getApiKey;** it shows ***undefined***. Probably its because the data is not received from $http call. How to perform the AJAX call synchronously.

Comment: Don't do synchronous calls. They unleash foul creatures from the bowels of the netherworld. Instead, use callbacks to execute code after the ajax call has successfully completed.

Comment: I am unable to use promise. because orders is a factory and inside this factory I need other methods to use this api key. and all those methods are finally returned "return obj"

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/751484/jonathan-m), it's not best practice you not use synchronous calls with AJAX, instead, you can return a promisse as a funcion and use it later:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.factory("Service", function ($http) {
  var obj = {};
  obj.getApiKey = $http.get('test.txt').then(function (data) {
    return {'Authorization' : data.data};
  });
  return obj;
});

app.factory("Orders", function ($http, Service) {
  var obj = {};

  obj.getApiKey = Service.getApiKey.then(function(data){
      console.log(data);
      return data;
  });

  return obj;
});
```

In this case, the service is returning a promisse object, this way you can ensure values will be called successfully and data will be available after the call.

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.factory("Service", function ($http) {
  var obj = {};
  factory.get=function(success,error){
   $http.get('test.txt').then(function (data) {
     obj.getApiKey = {'Authorization' : data.data};
   });
  return obj;
  }
});
app.factory("Orders", function ($http, Service) {
  Service.get(suc,err);
  var suc=function()
  {
     var obj = {};
  var api_key = Service.getApiKey;
  console.log(api_key);
  return obj;
  }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Return a Promise from your service:

```
app.factory("Service", function ($http) {
   return {
       getApiKey: function() {
           return $http.get('test.txt');
       }
   };
});
```

Inject your service, and use the Promise API to get your data asynchronously:

```
app.factory("Orders", function ($http, Service) {
   var obj = {};
   var api_key = {};

   Service.getApiKey().then(function(apiKey) {
        api_key = apiKey.data;
   });
});
```